# Javascript Form Submit Failure

Tags: javascript

I have code on my website that isn't working, and I haven't been able to figure out why...

Here is the code:

```
if (self.location.href == top.location.href) {
     document.fastform.submit();
 document.getElementById(fastform).submit();
}
```

Now if I put something other than a form submit into the if statement, it works just fine.  It's just when I do the form submit code it never works...

Here is the form code:

```
<form id="fastform" name="fastform" ACTION="/amember.php">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="myurl" ID="myurl">
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Thanks for the help guys!

So far none of the suggestions work, I have tried several different variations like putting quotes around the fastform in getelementbyid.  Here is my entire javascript program:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function geturl() {
var locate = document.location
document.fastform.myurl.value = locate
}
window.onload = geturl; 

if (self.location.href == top.location.href) {
var f=document.forms.fastform; f.submit();
}

</script>
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Okay, so using some of the suggested code here I got it working.  The problem was the if statement was not being executed at the right time, I moved things around so that the if statement was executed LAST and everything started working.  Here is the complete (functioning) code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function geturl() {
var locate = document.location
document.fastform.myurl.value = locate
getmeoutofhere()
}
window.onload = geturl;

function getmeoutofhere() {
   if (self.location.href == top.location.href) {
   document.getElementById('fastform').submit();
   }
}
</script>
<form id="fastform" name="fastform" ACTION="/amember.php" style="visibility:hidden;">
<INPUT  TYPE="text" NAME="myurl" ID="myurl" />
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your function:

var f=document.forms.fastform;
f.submit();

and it's working completely fine

Comment: This suggestion did not work...added to my original post the entire program.

Comment: write above code in ur if block and i have checked it's working fine

Comment: I am using this code:

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function run()
 {

  if (self.location.href == top.location.href) 
  {
   var f=document.forms.fastform; 
   f.submit();
  }

 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
 
 <form id="fastform" name="fastform" ACTION="/amember.php">
 
 </form> 
 <input type="button" onclick="run();">
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: It wasn't necessarily the syntax, it was the order everything was being executed in.  I put the if statement inside a function as you suggested and set the function to run after the first function geturl and now it works! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('fastform').submit();
```

OR

```
var frm = document.getElementById('fastform');
frm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's *the* problem, but there's certainly *one* problem with the line:

```
document.getElementById(fastform).submit();
```

The problem, I think, is that you're trying to get an element by its `id`, but `getElementById()` requires a quoted string, unless you've already assigned the string to the variable represented by `fastform`. Therefore it should be either:

```
document.getElementById('fastform').submit();
```

*or*:

```
var fastform = 'fastform';
document.getElementById(fastform).submit();
```

Further, you seem to be trying to work with the `fastform` variable before it *seems* to have been set, in the first line contained within the `if` statement:

```
document.fastform.submit();
```

I'd suggest amending your script a little, to be something like:

```
if (self.location.href == top.location.href) {
     var fastform = document.getElementById('fastform');
     fastform.submit();
}
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).